# How can stop android device back button from going back to splash screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I use this code for flutter app when I press the back button from home screen in android device  than it go back to splash screen. How can I stop this?

```
    abstract class Routes {
      Routes._();
      static const HOME = _Paths.HOME;
    }
    
    abstract class _Paths {
      _Paths._();
      static const HOME = '/home';
    }
    
    
   
    class AppPages {
      AppPages._();
    
      static const INITIAL = Routes.HOME;
    
      static final routes = [
        GetPage(
          name: _Paths.HOME,
          page: () => const SplashView(),
          binding: HomeBinding(),
        ),
      ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your entire screen with this custom widget (recommend extracting it to its own file tho and just calling it by name):

```dart
import 'package:back_button_interceptor/back_button_interceptor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavBlocker extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBlocker({
    super.key,
    required this.blocking,
    required this.child,
  });

  final bool blocking;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<NavBlocker> createState() => _NavBlockerState();
}

class _NavBlockerState extends State<NavBlocker> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
    return widget.blocking;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

... then just set the `blocking` bool to be either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

i use Go_route package to manage navigation .. and i get rid of the onboarding page like :
[image]

Comment: I  use get package can you please guide me according to it